# How to use a service from directive to call a function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-services

**controller**

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myCtrl', [  '$mdDialog', '$mdMedia', 'viewDialog', myCtrl]);
..

function myCtrl(  $mdDialog, $mdMedia, viewDialog) {   
    $scope.viewItem = function(ev,id) {
        viewDialog.ITEM(ev,id)
    };
}
```

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <md-list-item ng-repeat="item in myarr">
     <a  my-view-dialog">
       <h4> {{item.id}} </h4>
     </a>
  </md-list-item>
</div>
```

When I call the function directly form controller the modal window works fine on click

using the directive

My directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myViewDialog', function ($parse) {
        return {
            compile: function(tElm,tAttrs){
              var exp = $parse('viewItem($event,item.id)')
              return function (scope,elm){
                elm.bind('click',function(){
                  exp(scope);
                });
              };
            }
        };;
    });
```

Now I want to remove the controller dependency and directly call the viewDialog service from the directive it does not work.

here is code for service injection

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myViewDialog', function ($parse, viewDialog) {
        return {
            compile: function(tElm,tAttrs){
              var exp = $parse('viewDialog.ITEM($event,item.id)') 
          return function (scope,elm){
                elm.bind('click',function(){
                  exp(scope);
                });
              };
            }
          };;
    });
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the console?

Comment: What happens? Errors on the console?

Comment: No console error is there

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
.directive('myViewDialog', function ($parse, viewDialog)
```

Try

```
.directive('myViewDialog', [ '$parse', 'viewDialog', function ($parse, viewDialog)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myViewDialog',['viewDialog','$parse', function (viewDialog,$parse) {
    return {
        compile: function(tElm,tAttrs){
          var exp = $parse('viewDialog.ITEM($event,item.id)') 
      return function (scope,elm,attr,ctrl){
            elm.bind('click',function(){
              exp(scope);
            });
          };
        }
      };;
}]);
```

Comment: Directive get the rootScope by default.

Comment: I tried it but not getting any error on clicking, but still not working

Comment: if you want to give a specific control then you provide it.otherwise leave it as it is.